# Get computer or script state at last shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, python, shutdown

I had a Linux machine running a Python script for several days that eventually became nonresponsive, and the only thing I was able to do was a hard shutdown. Is there any way I can diagnose what was happening at the time I turned it off?

Comment: First place to look, for me, would be the system logs. This is far from being an ultimate solution, but definitely the starting point.

Comment: do you mean just the logs at `/var/log/syslog`? I checked, but there didn't seem to be anything particularly relevant

Comment: `/var/log/syslog` and/or `/var/log/messages` or `systemd` journal, it really depends on you specific installation/configuration.